# Calculate Studentized residuals, H leverage, Hat matrix and Cook's distance for SVM regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, python, outliers

I have developed a SVM regression model based on rbf kernel in python. The data set has 120 samples with 4 features.

I would like to know if it would be appropriate to apply outlier analysis on my SVM model by using Studentized residuals, H leverage, William's plot and Cook's distance.

Majority of the applications demonstrate the application of this outlier analysis for Least square optimization models only. Please highlight any specific approach to be followed for SVM regression.

An example demonstrating the application of these outlier analysis concepts on SVM regression will be really helpful.

Comment: I would like to see some light on the application of Outlier analysis for support vector regression ...